# forcing grid cell to lose focus programmatically and commit changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sqldataadapter

In my Win-Form application I am updating database from `DataGridview` using `SqlDataAdapter`.

I am using `MenuStripItme` and `ctrl + s` shortcut to invoke update function.

The problem is that the currently editing cell is not losing focus thus data is not committing to database. If I use button for this purpose or manually click outside the cell then it works fine.

I've tried below mentioned methods but no luck:

```
myGridView.EndEdit();
myGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
myGridView.ClearSelection();
```

here is the function for saving data to database.

```
private void saveMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Update(table);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Surely the savemenuitem_click needs to call the gridview endedit/commit/etc.. if you made that a method, you could call that method from both areas

Comment: Add a change event for WinForms that will fire when the property changes. Take a look at the INotifyPropertyChanged interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Comment: In case dgw.`CellEndEdit` won't work, try `CellEndEdit()` on the `CurrentCell`. You might also need to move the `CurrentCell` to a different one. As stupid as this 2nd step is, it resolves many issues. And may block events even if you have `SelectionMode` = `FullRowSelect`, which is wierd.

Comment: Oak_3260548: Can't find dgv.CurrentCell.CellEndEdit();

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
grdAtivoItem.CloseEditor();
grdAtivoItem.UpdateCurrentRow();
```

I call this on save click event